# How to use a regex replace to correct "Equals avoid Null" from checkstyle

Tags: java, regex, checkstyle

EDIT : I edited my post at the end to give the regex I used

Having sonar to monitor quality of a code is great, but on the downside, with crappy project, you have to correct a lot.
My problem is that I need to correct about 500 "Equals avoid Null" violations from checkstyle ( com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.EqualsAvoidNullCheck ).
With one regex to correct it semi automatically would be great.

The goal of this violation is to change

```
myObject.getMyMember().toString().equals("one string")
```

to

```
"one string".equals(myObject.getMyMember().toString())
```

---

EDIT : 
I used this way and it worked well even if I need to check it and not launch a sed on my entire source tree

The regex to match the total line

```
([\(|& \t!])([^\(|& \t!])([a-zA-Z0-9_\[\]\(\)\.]*)\.(equals|equalsIgnoreCase)\(("[^"]*")\)
```

The regex to replace the line for

```
\1\5.\4(\2\3)
```

It took me a day to correct the 500 violations. Still a lot of work, but it would have been more painful if I had to do it by hand.

Comment: It doesn't avoid the null checks. A NullPointerException would still be thrown. Think about it again, you will see why.

Comment: don't take short cuts - treat the exercise in tedium as penance for your sins.  In any event, you still need null checks on `myObject` and `myObject.getMyMember()` ...

Comment: Right Matijn and Alnitak, I don't know why I said that ...
Anyway, I don't like penitence which should be taken by others :p

Comment: @beny23 yes, you would.  Just because `.equals()` can take an object doesn't mean that object will have its `.toString()` method invoked automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain it is the solution but try :

> 

```
final String sTmp = myObject.getMyMember();
    if(null != sTmp) {<br>
    // Test .equals() here <br>
    ..<br>
```

}